# Disable traces in debug mode visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, trace

I have a lot of traces in my application and it takes a long time to start in debug mode.
Is there anyway to disable tarces in visual studio 2013 ?
thanks

Comment: You've got an IntelliTrace entry in Tools > options, where you can disable... Intellitrace. Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: i'm looking for a way to make traces not to write to visual studio output,cause i think this is what makes my application takes long time when i launch it in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for (I don't quite understand what traces you are trying to disable), but you can filter the messages that are shown in the output window (while in Debug mode, right click in Output window):
[image]

If this is not it, can you let me know more about your scenario? Do you happen to have a lot of exceptions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to

1. Supress both `Trace & Debug` message from whole application then at application startup use

   ```
   Trace.Listeners.Clear();
   ```
2. Supress only `Trace` message from whole application then in project properties page in build tab. Remove `TRACE` symbol from conditional compilation TextBox
   [image]
3. Use `#undef TRACE` or `#undef DEBUG`   at top line in `*.cs` file to supress trace or debug message from that `*.cs` file only.